# Update from select only if single result from select

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to populate a newly created field in a table based on pre-existing data in another table and I have come up with this

```
UPDATE tb1
SET tb2Id = (SELECT tb2.tb2ID
             FROM tb2
             WHERE tb2.f1 = tb1.f1)
```

The problem is that some values of f1 appear more than once in tb2. In those cases I want the value of tb2Id in tb1 to be null. How can I achieve this.

Update: The column tb1.tb2Id has only just been added to the table so every row is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update with a join while limiting the rows in tb1 to only the ones that occur only once in t2 with the subquery.

```
UPDATE tb1
  SET tbl1.tb2Id = tbl2.tb2ID
FROM tb1
JOIN tbl2 
ON tb1.f1 = tb2.f1
WHERE tbl1.f1 IN
    (SELECT f1
     FROM tbl2
     GROUP BY f1
     HAVING COUNT(1) = 1)
```

Comment: Almost what I was after - I've clarified that because this is a new column, all rows are null so just need to set the value only on rows where there is exactly 1 matching record.
If you tweak your answer I will mark as answer.